# Reaching from one string to another using given dictionary

Tags: arrays, algorithm, validation, dictionary, data-structures

For this question, a dictionary was given and two strings also given, it was basically asked to reach from one string to another one just using the words in dictionary, and only one letter can be changed at a time. I came up with this solution. There were some corner cases that my code can not handle. Can you help to find all the corner cases to make this code prettier?

```
public static int findNumberOfSteps(String start, String end , HashSet<String> dict){

    if( start == null || end == null || dict.isEmpty()){

        throw new IllegalArgumentException();           
    }

    dict.add(end);

    Queue<String> wordHolder = new LinkedList<>(); 
    Queue<Integer> distanceCount = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    wordHolder.add(start);
    distanceCount.add(1);
    int result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    while (!wordHolder.isEmpty()){

        String currentWord = wordHolder.poll();
        int currDistance = distanceCount.poll();


        if(currentWord.equals(end)){
            int result = currDistance;
            return result;
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < currentWord.length() ; i++){

            char[] charCurrentWord = currentWord.toCharArray();

            for ( char c = 'a' ; c <= 'z' ; c++){

                charCurrentWord[i] = c;

                String newWord = new String(charCurrentWord);


                if (dict.contains(newWord)){

                    wordHolder.add(newWord);
                    distanceCount.add(currDistance+1);
                    dict.remove(newWord);                       
                }                   
            }               
        }           
    }       
    return 0;               
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in the code. The first problem is in this code

```
if(currentWord.equals(end)){
    result = Math.min(result, currDistance);
}
```

Note that when you reach the `end` word, that code updates the `result`, but then the code is going to search for ways to change the `end` word to something else. That's a huge waste of time, the code should continue with the `while(!wordHolder.isEmpy())` loop after the `end` is found.

The second problem is in this code

```
if (dict.contains(newWord)){
    wordHolder.add(newWord);
    distanceCount.add(currDistance+1);
    dict.remove(newWord);                       
}
```

Note that if `newWord` is equal to the `end` word, then that code **removes the `end` word** from the dictionary, which means that you'll never find the `end` word again.

The solution to both problems is to check for the `end` word inside that `if` statement. When the `end` is found, don't add it to the `wordHolder` and don't remove it from the dictionary.

```
if (dict.contains(newWord)){
    if(newWord.equals(end)){
        result = Math.min(result, currDistance+1);
    }
    else{
        wordHolder.add(newWord);
        distanceCount.add(currDistance+1);
        dict.remove(newWord);
    }                       
}
```

Comment: In logical way, if newWord is equal to the end, that means I have just found the number of steps needed to be taken to reach the end word, after that time for loop will work and will not be able to find anything,so result will not be updated at all, as soon as for loop ended, the code will print the result which have been found when newWord is equal to end . what is wrong with this?

Comment: @GökhanAkduğan I see your point. Since you're doing a breadth-first-search, the first time you find `end` should be the shortest distance. That being the case, you could just `return currDistance+1` as soon as you find `end`. There's no need for the `Math.min` in the code.

Comment: you are right, i will update it like that in order to increase efficiency.thanks